# How can I start a React app from terminal that has C# controllers?

Tags: c#, reactjs

I have a reactjs app that has controllers written in c#. I have a c# service that makes a call to the controller via the following syntax

```
const getUserDetails = (userId) => {
  return data_post('user/GetUser/' + userId, {})
}
```

That in turn calls my controller which is a c# file residing in a directory Controller under ClientApp and it returns the data to the js file in the ClientApp directory.

Now when I want to start my React app, I do so via the following:

```
npm start
```

But the issue is when i try to call any of these it says that the controller is not recognized. that is how can i start the react front end and the .net web API backend?

I have tried running the app using npm start --prefix .\ClientApp\ , still didn't work.

How can I start the app and make sure that the API/controllers are loaded?

Comment: just to confirm - you're running _everything_ locally?

Comment: yes i am .. i can run it from visual studio by clicking on Run /F5 . but i want to be able to compile it via command line and run it because i need to deploy it

Comment: the complete error is :   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found):  user/GetUser/   ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to first ensure that your C# backend is running...

The 404 status code for user/GetUser endpoint indicates that there is no such endpoint.

It's true since you're not running the backend.

Depending on the complexity of your app you should figure out what classes to run BUT the basic terminal command for compiling C# is "csc myClass.cs" and then "./myClass.exe" to execute the compiled solution.

Comment: _"The 404 status code for user/GetUser endpoint indicates that there is no such endpoint."_ - No, but it does imply a HTTP server is listening to that address and `Host:` header, so the C# code is very likely _running_, but the OP might have the path wrong, sure.

Comment: @Dai OP mentioned using `npm start`, so I rather doubt that the C# code is running.

Comment: @Brian `npm start` would be to start the frontend, the backend process/project is presumably already running. When I'm doing simultaneous frontend+backend work I typically start the backend first, then the frontend.

Comment: @Dai Agreed, that would be the usual way.  But the OP mentioned running it from their IDE normally, so I suspect they may be trying `npm start` without a corresponding `dotnet run`.  It's hard to tell from the OP's description, though.

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` only run the react front-end. Your back-end api doesn't run so it cannot be recognized.
If the webapi hasn't been published yet, you should have a ".csproj" file. In the same directory just use `dotnet run` in the CMD will run that api.

Comment: so do i do a dotnet run User.csproj and then npm start --prefix .\ClientApp\ , ?

Comment: @Belinda This depending on how is your project configured. If you try the visual studio "react with asp.net core" template. When run `dotnet run` , the reactjs will also run automatically. Because there are configurations in the backend to start reactjs at the same time.

Comment: I now get the error: Nuget connection attempt failed "Unable to load the service index for source" for telerik ?

Comment: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorised)  [c:\proj\GetUser.csproj]

Comment: @Belinda 401 means this back-end is protected by some authentication scheme.  you could post the program.cs or startup.cs file code to let us check what authentication you are using. I guess you should have something like `service.addidentity`